# error : "protocol methods may not have bodies" in Swift

Tags: swift, error-handling

I am having this error in Swift:

> "protocol methods may not have bodies"

Comment: You should only have a method signature. Solution: remove the `{}` after your function declaration.

Comment: Protocols don't have implementation but if you'd like a default function for a protocol you can write a extension for this protocol with the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

That means you tried to actually implement a method inside a protocol declaration - protocols define the signature of the method, but the implementation has to be in a class / struct / enum.

Comment: The implementation can also be in an extension. Something like: `extension SomeProtocol { func someFunction() {} }`

Answer (score 2):

Some code would be very helpful when posting questions on stack overflow, especially when it's about a compilation error.

However the problem is because you are implementing the body of a protocol method, which is not allowed for swift protocols - what you can do is just declare methods and properties, but the implementation is left to classes and structs that adopt that protocol.

I suggest you to read some documentation about [swift protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_402)